# Does using var in a tight JavaScript loop increase memory-related overhead?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

For example, would this:

```
while (true) {
    var random = Math.random();
}
```

... be less efficient than the following, in most implementations?

```
var random;
while (true) {
    random = Math.random();
}
```

Thanks for your input.

**Edit**: In case it wasn't obvious, I'm mostly worried about lots of repeated (de)allocations occurring in this example.

Comment: As it might seem, the inside the loop variable, with a limited scope, will be recreated everytime it loops, as its space in memory and its pointer. I may be talking horse feathers, but in my opnion, the declaration outside the loop will be more effecient than the inside.

Comment: @NoProblem: JavaScript does not have block scope. Please don't misinform. This is not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**JavaScript does not have block scoping.**

In the first example, the `var text` declaration is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting) out of the `while` block. In both cases, the variable is declared only once. In both cases, the variable is assigned a value once per iteration of the `while` loop.

### [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#var)

- `function`-scoped
- hoist to the top of its function
- redeclarations of the same name in the same scope are no-ops

Comment: I see, thanks! So, by this virtue, this:

`var random;`

`var interval = setInterval(foo, 100);`

`function foo() { random = Math.random();`

is actually faster than if the `var` was moved inside of foo?

Comment: @BHSPit keeping the declaration outside is not necessarily _faster_. I can say there will _probably_ be fewer memory allocations with `var` outside, but there are many other considerations. For example, the browser might perform different optimizations with the declaration inside rather than outside. Something else that might affect the speed is the variable lookup inside of `foo`.

Comment: @BHSPit for the most part, this is all probably micro-optimization, but you might be interested in reading [High Performance JavaScript](http://books.google.com/books?id=ED6ph4WEIoQC&lpg=PP1&dq=high%20performance%20javascript&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false). It's a well-written book. I have a copy on my desk right now.

Comment: Update for 2019.  JavaScript does now have block scoping with `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 1):

No, variables are initiated upon entry into the scope, so `random` exists before the var statement is even reached.

Comment: Your answer is missing crucial information: that JS does not have block scope, only function (and global) scope.

Comment: My point is that iterating over the `var` statement multiple times in the same scope does nothing in JavaScript than if the `var` is done outside the loop.

Comment: Right... but the only reason that's the case is that JS does not have block scope, which the OP clearly isn't aware of. If JS did have block scope, then the variable might still be 'initiated upon entry into the scope" (as you say), but "the scope" would mean "the body of the `while` loop" rather than "the body of the function."

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have block scope, and `random`'s declaration would be hoisted to the top of its scope anyway ([variable object](http://tore.darell.no/pages/scope_in_javascript)).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the implementation of the interpreter. Strictly speaking, yes, it may have a slightly higher overhead; but depending on the GC mechanism this should be cleared reasonably quickly too.

Answer (score 0):

[Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations) recommends putting all the var assignments at the top of a function, i.e. outwith any loops.